# Data Deletion Foreign Key Validation Best Practice

Tags: database, rest, architecture

What is the best practice regarding validating a deletion.

For example, I have the tables

Units and Products, every product must have a unit as the data is related, if you try to delete data from units that are in a product the system will throw an error.

**My doubt is:**

- I let the system throw the error and deal with the error.
- Create validations (Example, select from the product table checking if there is a product with that unit)

Or is there a more recommended option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In general* it's best to avoid using exceptions for flow control for lots of reasons.  Things like creating stack-traces can be expensive, doing a write transaction is more expensive than a read (and can often only be done on the primary).  The general rule is that exceptions should be exceptional, and if you can reasonably anticipate them as part of the flow of your application, you should.

This is a "rule of thumb", and depending on your application, it may be really uncommon.  If you generally expect the consumers of your API to be aware of the constraint, and to "clean up" before deletion, then you can probably leave it an exception.   If it's the normal course to try and delete, and then react to the error by going and looking at the other table, then you should try harder to not make this an error.